# Cell text won't appear in iOS 7 TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've tried so many things and I'm totally at a loss. My text isn't appearing in my cell's default text labels in TableView. The strange part is everything else does work. By that I mean, I can read and parse the data source (XML), I can create the right amount of rows (5), and I can even get the cells to contain the text data. I know this because when I use NSLog it shows this. I even double check by using didSelectRowAtIndexPath and `NSLog(@"%@",cellText);` and the right text is in the log! So the cell text label contains the text I want, but it's still not appearing on the screen. Instead, I just get 5 blank rows that are each selectable, and will display the right text in the NSLog when I select them but not on the screen.

I've tried the following fixes: adjusting backgroundColor and textColor (nope), trying different sample code I could find online (nope), using ViewControllers instead of TableViewControllers (nope), deleting the files and re-building them (nope), and even creating new projects with only this code to isolate the code (nope). Every time, it's still blank! I have no idea what to do.

Here's the code I'm using to grab and display the data in the tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [app.listArray count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = theList.name;

NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"%@",theList.name);

return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is a new plain project that does not have anything else that could interfere. You checked with NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text) that the text is populated, you verified that the background and foreground colors are not the same. One remaining thing to check is transparency/Alpha. Make sure it is set to 1.

If this is on the simulator, try testing on a device. If you can't test on a device, try different simulator device to rule out the possibility that it is a simulator glitch.

Also, try hardcoding the label text to something like @"Abcdef" to make sure that the source of the culprit is not the data you are trying to display.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, it is something with the data. I tried hardcoding the label with @"Test" like you recommended and it worked. As for a simulator glitch, I forgot to mention I did test on a device and the problem was still there. That being said, do you have any other thoughts on what might be going on with the data?

Comment: With your help I figured it out! What could the data be doing? It could be too big! Sure enough, I changed the number of lines in the text label from 1 to 2 and it solved the problem :) Thank you Mirek!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way. see how I wrote cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listArray count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


 [cell.titleLabel setText:[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"%@",theList.name);

return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem but the answer to my problem was the Connection Inspector on the right hand side for the cell. The Outlet needs to be set to accessoryView for the ContentView. Just drag it over to the cell. Don't feel bad I pulled my hair out too.

Im using Xcode7 Beta and Swift